# c++ when to include cpp even if we have .h file

Tags: c++

I am reading the book Absolute C++ 5th edition.
In page 716, 
I don't really understand why it needs include "pfarray.cpp"

Is include "pfarray.h" not enough?

More specifically, even if we have declarations in .h file but implementations in .cpp files, when we still have to include .cpp file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a general rule, #including cpp files is never necessary. It is possible to write cpp files that *must* #include each other, but doing so is never necessary and almost never good practice.

Comment: When you say "include .cpp file", do you mean using `#include` or do you mean including the .cpp file in the project?

Comment: One use case is, when you have definitions of `template` functions inside that .cpp file.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `#include anything.any_extension`, the extension doesn't really matter to the preprocessor. It's really like a *"take the contents from that file and paste it into this file"* kind of brute mechanism. So you can include anything without error provided that the code inside is legit, and you can name a header file with any extension. So you can even name them with a `.txt` extension and it wouldn't really matter to the preprocessor.

I would suggest that the practice of including source files is rather confusing, mainly from a build standpoint since it's not very clear whether a source file (cpp, cc, etc) is supposed to be built as a separate object file to link against or #included or both.

Yet it's sometimes done anyways. For example, `pfarray.cpp` might contain an implementation for a template since templates typically need their full implementation visible at compile time at the site generating the code, and sometimes authors establish a habit of #including files with source file extensions to avoid putting the implementation details into the same header file while uniformly conforming to a style that favors putting all such details into files named with a source file convention.

Another reason this can be done, but I don't think it's the reason it was done in your case, is as a build optimization (see Unity builds). It can sometimes be more efficient to compile and link fewer files, so using `#include` for source files can be a crude way to fuse them all together into a single build target.

Comment: Is there a good reason to put a template definition in `pfarray.cpp` rather than `pfarray.h`?

Comment: No in my opinion, but some people like the practicality of uniformly having their debuggers step into cpp files for implementation details, e.g.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't surprise me that people who `#include "pfarray.cpp"` spend a lot of their time in debuggers.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to.

A translation unit is a group of files with definitions and declarations. Compiling a translation unit, the compiler needs to know everything about declarations and re-parse them again and again. The definitions on the other hand can be compiled just once and reused for another units.

A translation unit can be separated in `.h` and `.cpp` files. You should put the declarations in `.h` and definitions in `.cpp` files to obey one definition rule. This approach also reduces compilation time.

Writing template-d classes and functions (without specialization), some coders (a bad habit in my opinion) will put the implementations in the `.cpp` files and they have to include them at the end of its corresponding `.h` file or in a `.cpp` file which needs them. It's just confusing. A better naming convention is to rename these type of `.cpp` files to `.impl.cpp` and including them at the end of its `.h` file.